# OLEDB.oracle provider not found

Tags: excel, oracleclient, vba

I am hitting a strange problem with an Excel VBA application that accesses an Oracle database. The application works perfectly in development and in test, but when it was installed on to a VM for support to use, it says that it cannot find the data provider or the data provider may not have been installed properly.

Normally, the issue would be that the Oracle Client hasn't been installed with the OLE Database Provider missing, but this is all installed and there is nothing blocking. SQL Developer can access the database, and so I am confused as to what the problem could be.

It is Oracle 12c Client that is being used, and as I said - everything is working fine in development and in test.

Can someone throw some light on to this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Excel 2010. A colleague installed a 64bit version of Office 2010 rather than the standard version. When this was installed, it worked. So, be careful when installing Office 2010